# Find duplicate records and display in when searched for in lookup field

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Find all records that are duplicates of a record in the entity. There is a requirement where a user can enter the Name field of the entity record in a text box on the form. On the change event of this text box the system must select all records that are duplicates of this record entered and display their 'name' field in the lookup field so that the user can select a duplicate record from the lookup field. I was wondering if you can give me an idea how to achieve this in Dynamics 365. Does it need a custom workflow to accomplish this? Please let me know your thoughts of how I can achieve this in Dynamics 365 version 9.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a candidate for PCF control development, so you can do the search using api and fill the typeable combobox control to choose from the list. Something similar to [this control](https://pcf.gallery/address-lookup/).

But can this not be utilized with an OOB lookup, self relationship to search with the name in lookup and choose it the way it works in CRM. I wonder.